# Given $a+b+c=3$ .Prove $ \sum \limits_{cyc} \frac {1}{a^2+b^2+2} \le \frac 34$

Tags: inequality

Yesterday I found this on the Internet:
Give 3 non-negative numbers $a,b,c$ that $a+b+c=3$. Prove
$$ \sum _{cyc} \frac  {1}{a^2+b^2+2} \le \frac 34 $$ 
I have tried to solve this using AM-GM:
From AM-GM we got: 
$$a^2+b^2+2\ge2(a+b)$$
$$\Rightarrow \frac{1}{a^2+b^2+2} \le \frac12\frac1{a+b}$$
$$\Rightarrow \sum _{cyc} \frac  {1}{a^2+b^2+2} \le \frac12\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a+b}$$
We have to prove $$\frac12\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a+b}\le\frac34$$
or  $$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a+b}\le\frac32$$
However the above statement seem to be false. If $a = 0 , b = 1, c = 2$:
$$\sum_{cyc}\frac{1}{a+b} = 1+\frac13+\frac12=\frac{11}6\gt \frac32$$
Anyone know the solutions?

Comment: When you make the estimate $$s_1 = \sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{a^2 + b^2 + 2} \leq \frac{1}{2} \sum_{cyc} \frac{1}{a+b} = s_2$$ you are going above $\frac{3}{4}$ (at least for some $a,b,c$). This is why you found your counterexample. From $s_1 \leq s_2$ and $s_2 \nleq 3/4 $ you cannot say anything about $s_1$ (though it's true that $s_1 \leq 3/4$), and therefore you need another way to prove the inequality.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's suffice to show the following inequality $$ \sum\limits_{sic}{\frac{a^2+b^2}{a^2+b^2+2}} \ge \frac{3}{2} $$ By using Cauchy, we have $$ LHS \ge \frac{\left(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+\sqrt{b^2+c^2}+\sqrt{c^2+a^2}\right)^2}{2\left(a^2+b^2+c^2\right)+6} \ge \frac{\sqrt{3\left(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2\right)}+2\left(a^2+b^2+c^2\right)}{\left(a^2+b^2+c^2\right)+3} $$ Notice that $ \sqrt{3\left(a^2b^2+b^2c^2+c^2a^2\right)} \ge ab+bc+ca $, thus, the last term is greater than $$ \frac{2\left(a^2+b^2+c^2\right)+\left(ab+bc+ca\right)}{\left(a^2+b^2+c^2\right)+3} = \frac{3}{2} $$ The conclusion follows. Note that $ a+b+c=3 $ implies $ a^2+b^2+c^2+2ab+2bc+2ca=9 $.

Comment: Why does it suffice to show that?

Comment: Since $$ \sum\limits_{cyc}\left(\frac{a^2+b^2}{a^2+b^2+2}\right)+2\left(\sum\limits_{cyc}{\frac{1}{a^2+b^2+2}}\right)=3 $$

Comment: I don't understand why $\sum _{cyc} {\frac {a^2+b^2}{a^2+b^2+2} }\ge \frac{(\sqrt{a+b}+\sqrt{b+c}+\sqrt{c+a})^2}{2(a^2+b^2+c^2)+6}  $.I have known the Engel form of Cauchy - Schwarz inequality, which state $\sum _{cyc} {\frac{a^2}x}\ge \frac {(a+b+c)^2}{x+y+z}$, but if we use this inequality, it must be $\sum _{cyc} {\frac {a^2+b^2}{a^2+b^2+2} }\ge \frac{(\sqrt{a^2+b^2}+\sqrt{b^2+c^2}+\sqrt{c^2+a^2})^2}{2(a^2+b^2+c^2)+6}  $.Please answer me.

Comment: Because that's a typo...